# How to send message to Topic Subscription Dead Letter Queue Explicitly in Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azureservicebus

I want to create a Message object and explicitly send it to topic subscription dead letter queue via correlation filter. I cannot find anything that can do that. I've explored the Service Bus library, even the documentation says I can do that on application level, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Messages can be dead-lettered by the broker only. What you can do is set-up a subscription with dead-lettering upon message TTL expiration and a TTL short enough that every message gets dead-lettered. This will mean that messages will have a dead-letter reason stated as expired TTL.

In general, I'd recommend not to abuse dead-lettering beyond what it was designed for.

Comment: What about sending the Message to Topic and later sending it to DLQ after receiving it by SubscriptionClient or MessageReceiver?

Comment: You cannot send anything to the DLQ yourself. The broker can. See my answer ☺️

Comment: Thanks alot, sir. 

Comment: You can add a processor listening to subscription/queue and as soon as you get a message - shift that to the DLQ

Comment: @abhijat_saxena sure thing, but why?! You'll pay for sending, receiving, and dead-lettering. In general, I'd suggest not to use dead-letter queue as a storage mechanism. Just because something can be done, doesn't mean it should be 

Answer (score 0):

Your subscription client object has a DeadLetterAsync method.  Send to the Topic and have your listener dead letter it.